# Angular 4 dynamically create component inside another component using a directive

Tags: angular, components, directive, angular-directive, angular-components

For example

```
<my-component1 my-directive="true">

     //dynamically load my-component2 if my-directive is true
     <my-component2 someProp="someProperties from my-component1">

</my-component1>
```

I've been looking everywhere but can't seem to find a clear way to do this...

Comment: Is the first component already in DOM or you want to dynamically add component with another component inside? Have you figure out how to solve it yet?

Comment: load a component dynamically in angular https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LjCOe1PcP5g

Comment: instead of a directive I think I just used a prop and onInit check for the prop and dynamically load the component